# What do you call someone who is emotionally strong?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

A noun describing a person who is emotionally strong.

For example:

> My Aunt Sally was the **[emotionally strong person]** in our family.

Comment: Often, simply *strong*. As in a *strong, independent woman*, which has nothing to do with being able to lift enormous weights.

Comment: You could say the person is a "rock." - "My wife was by my side; she's the rock in our relationship."

Comment: What's wrong with *emotionally strong*? I don't believe you will find a single word which says exactly that, though there are many which come close..

Comment: @WS2 That's not a word.

Comment: Why the close votes? SWRs almost always hit us simple and direct like this.

Comment: @Kris You are quite right, it is not *a word*. It is two words. Sometimes it takes more than one to explain what you mean!

Answer (score 5):

I was originally going to suggest "Stoic", "Stalwart" and "Unflappable", but they won't work since you're looking for a specific noun. (Though, they're still good adjectives you should look into.)

You might say "**[Pillar of Strength](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/pillar)**" here, or perhaps even "Foundation" (Though foundation is typically used for ideals in this sense). These words evoke images of steadiness in troubling times and are usually equatable to people who are emotionally strong, bearing any hardships without breaking under pressure.

I don't know if there is an exact word for an emotionally strong person, but as allusions, these will almost certainly convey what you want.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular context

**[anchor](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/anchor)**

> A person or thing which provides stability or confidence in an otherwise uncertain situation

Or possibly

**[keystone](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/keystone#nav1)**

> The central principle or part of a policy, system, etc., on which all else depends

Answer (score 0):

resilient -
recovering readily from illness, depression, adversity, or the like; buoyant.

Comment: Thanks for including a definition.  Did it come from a particular dictionary?  Including the reference would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Ancient Greeks left us this philosophy, and the **stoic** adjective.
**:** One who is seemingly indifferent to or unaffected by joy, grief, pleasure, 
 impassive: "stoic resignation in the face of hunger" (John F. Kennedy).